# XSLT - display child elements located in different XML files

Tags: php, xml, xslt, amazon-product-api

I have the following `movies.xml` file that stores movie titles and Amazon API ItemId for dvd and bluray:

```
<movies
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="movies.xsd">

<movie movieID="1">
    <title>The Dark Knight</title>
    <amazon>
        <dvd>B004Q9SZGC</dvd>
        <bluray>B004Q9T6CO</bluray>
    </amazon>
</movie>

<movie movieID="2">
    <title>Lawless</title>
    <amazon>
        <dvd>B008OPZ83C</dvd>
        <bluray>B008OPZD8C</bluray>
    </amazon>
</movie>

</movies>
```

`movies_list.xsl` displays movie titles as hyperlinkes that take the user to the `movie_details` page where they can see
the movie title they have clicked on AND its corresponding Amazon dvd and bluray product information:

movies_list.xsl

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
        <xsl:element name="head">
            <xsl:element name="h2">Movies list</xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="body">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="movies/movie"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">movie_details.php?movieID=<xsl:value-of select="@movieID"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>
```

`movie_details.php` looks up and displays movie information (dvd and bluray) from Amazon API XML:

```
$movies = file_get_contents('movies.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($movies);

$movieId = $_GET['movieID'];
$movie = $xml->xpath("/movies/movie[@movieID = '$movieId']")[0];
if($movie) {
   $dvd = $movie->amazon->dvd;
   $bluray = $movie->amazon->bluray;

    $request = aws_signed_request('co.uk', array(
            'Operation' => 'ItemLookup',
            'ItemId' => $dvd.', '.$bluray,
            'ResponseGroup' => 'Medium, Offers',
            'MerchantId' => 'All'), $public_key, $private_key, $associate_tag); 

    $response = @file_get_contents($request);

    $xml2 = new DOMDocument();
    $xml2->loadXML($response);

    $xsl = new DOMDocument;
    $xsl->load('movie_details.xsl');

    $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
    $proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

    $params = $_GET['movieID'];
    $proc->setParameter('', 'movieID', $params);

    echo $proc->transformToXML($xml2);

}
```

Instead of hardcoding the actual ItemId values into the array, I have created $dvd and $bluray variables
that look up ItemId for dvd and bluray stored in the local `movies.xml` file.

This is my `movie_details.xsl` file that displays all the movie details information: title (from movies.xml) and Amazon DVD and Bluray pictures (from Amazon API):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:aws="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01"
exclude-result-prefixes="aws">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="moviesXML" select="document('movies.xml')"/>

<xsl:param name="movieID"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="html">
        <xsl:element name="head">
            <title>Movie details</title>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="body">  
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$moviesXML/movies/movie[@movieID=$movieID]" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="movie">
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:element name="br" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item/aws:MediumImage/aws:URL"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="aws:URL">
    <xsl:element name="img">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Based on the movie title that the user has clicked on in the `movies_list` page, it should take him to the `movie_details` page
that will display that specific movie title and its corresponding Amazon dvd and bluray URL (link to the product cover picture) which in turn will be displayed as a picture.

I do get the movie title displayed on the `movie_details` page based on the movie title the user has clicked on in the `movies_list` page.

However, I am not sure where do I need to put:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items/aws:Item/aws:MediumImage/aws:URL"/>
```

To also display that movie's Amazon DVD and bluray product information.

The end result that I want to achieve:

[image: display]

Movie ID 2 should work the same way except it will display Lawless movie information instead of the Dark Knight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do here is store a reference to the root of the input XML:

```
<xsl:variable name="moviesXML" select="document('movies.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="inputRoot" select="/" />
```

Then you can do this in your second template:

```
<xsl:template match="movie">
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    <xsl:element name="br" />
    <xsl:apply-templates 
       select="$inputRoot/aws:ItemLookupResponse/aws:Items
                 /aws:Item/aws:MediumImage/aws:URL"/>
</xsl:template>
```

It looks like you also need to modify the way you get the DVD and Blu-Ray IDs for your Amazon API request:

```
$movies = file_get_contents('movies.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($movies);

$movieId = $_GET['movieID'];
$movieSelect = $xml->xpath("/movies/movie[@movieID = '$movieId']");
$movie = $movieSelect[0];
if($movie) {
   $dvd = $movie->amazon->dvd;
   $bluray = $movie->amazon->bluray;

   // the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, JLRishe. This method makes perfect sense to me and it does work partially. No matter whether I click on The Dark Knight or Lawless titles in the movies_list page, movie_details page always displays The Dark Knight Amazon DVD and BluRay pictures. So for example if I click on Lawless, the page displays the title Lawless properly, but the DVD and BluRay covers are still displayed as Dark Knight which is movieID 1. Would it have something to do with my PHP code where I define $dvd and $bluray variables to read from the XML, so they only read the first record? Thank you.

Comment: So it looks like it always reads the first dvd and bluray ItemId's in the XML and displays them for every single movie title that I click on.

Comment: I think you need a modification to the way you get the DVD and BluRay ids to use in the AmazonAPI request. Please see the PHP code I've added above.

Comment: thank you for your help, JLRishe. I've updated my code with your solution but for some reason when I click on any of the movie titles the page displays "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error) An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request." I've updated my PHP code in my original post. Would it have something to do with $params that I'm using?

Comment: Hm, that's odd.  Could you delete and re-add parts to track down which line is causing the issue?  Could you also try doing an `echo $dvd . ' ' . $bluray;` after those two variables are set to verify that they have the expected values?

Comment: It seems like the following line causes the problem: $movie = $xml->xpath("/movies/movie[@movieID = '$movieId']")[0]; " If I remove it and leave everything else then I don't get a Server 500 error but "Notice: Undefined variable: movie" since that line is where the variable is defined. If I leave that line but remove the "[0]" at the end then I get a "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object". So I can't even echo anything with that line in my code

Comment: I see. Could you try my modified code above. I've split that line into two separate lines.

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you so much for your help, JLRishe. Without you I would not be able to solve this problem!